# How to configure UNIX or Linux for administration via serial connection

Tags: console, serial

How can I configure my UNIX or/and Linux PC with COM port to support serial console connections? I would like to connect my notebook to that PC via a console cable and manage the PC with terminal emulation software like putty, as if I use keyboard directly.

Comment: And FreeBSD ? Solaris ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have this line in `/etc/inittab` on a server I run that has a serial console:

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 57600 vt100
```

`ttyS0` is the serial port.  That's all there is to it, at least here.

**Edit**: You'll probably want something like this in your grub.conf:

```
serial --unit=0 --speed=57600
terminal --timeout=10 serial console
```

And then with each kernel:

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz ro root=/dev/md1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,57600
```

(The important part is the `console=` arguments)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, I'd suggest looking here:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/

Specifically, the GRUB section so that you can get the boot menu too (not just the OS once it begins to load):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-kernel-grub.html

Comment: Yep, having this for the boot process as well as later stages is highly recommended, especially if you're going to rely on it as the main/sole means of access.

Answer (score 3):

See the other answers if your distro uses `inittab`. But Ubuntu uses `/etc/event.d` and most other distros are or will as they adopt the more modern init daemon *Upstart*. At least it will eventually get rid of those hideous System V "run levels".

If you do have a `/etc/event.d/`, in there you should have `tty1`, `tty2`, **...**. You may need to copy one of the `tty` files to `ttyS0`. (Check `/proc/devices` to see what you have.)

These files look something like:

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc2
start on stopped rc3
start on stopped rc4
start on stopped rc5

stop on runlevel 0
stop on runlevel 1
stop on runlevel 6

respawn
exec /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

Be sure the device name and the speed are what you want.

Comment: Huh.  New to me!

Answer (score 2):

You just tell the machine you want to connect to with the serial console to listen on a serial port.  Most Linux distributions come with examples in their `/etc/inittab` files that show how to do it (look for `/dev/ttyS0`).